# SearchBoxEx: Custom search button text

Tags: search

Is there a way to configure a custom text for the search button?
This is what i want: [Custom search Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRTW0.jpg)

I know that i can configure a image for that, but instead of the image I want to set a text.

```
<Property Name="GoImageUrl">/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif</Property>
<Property Name="GoImageUrlRTL">/_layouts/images/goRTL.gif</Property>
<Property Name="GoImageActiveUrl">/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif</Property>
<Property Name="GoImageActiveUrlRTL">/_layouts/images/goRTL.gif</Property>
```

Or do I have to put the text in an image?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing it with some javascript code added to your masterpage's head?

for example

```
$(function() {
var theSearchBox = $('input#IdOftheInputControl');
var defaultSearchText = "Search this site";
var preferredSearchText = "Custom Search Text";

//replace the text initially
theSearchBox.val(preferredSearchText);

theSearchBox.focus(function() {
  if ($(this).val().indexOf(defaultSearchText) > -1)
    $(this).val(preferredSearchText);  

});
theSearchBox.blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val().indexOf(defaultSearchText) > -1)
    $(this).val(preferredSearchText);  

});

});
```

Please note the #IdOftheInputControl obviously needs to be changed to match the ID of the textbox in your site. You can look it up using any DOM explorer, most of the time it will be something like

```
ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_ctl01_S3031AEBB_InputKeywords
```

.
So the code becomes as below:

```
var theSearchBox = $(‘input#ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_ctl01_S3031AEBB_InputKeywords’);
```